# Meteor autoform Form hidden fields not rendering defaultValue and not saving

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have two hidden fields in my autoform Schema defined as shown below. I wish to save those two fields with other fields while not showing them to the app user. But I noticed from the autoform rendered html that the two hidden fields have no value, also they don't save with other fields to DB. Not sure what I might be missing / wrong here? Thanks for your help

```
  Invoice = new SimpleSchema({
    clientid: {
      type: String,
      optional: true
    },
    total: {
      type: String,
      label: 'Total Amount',
      optional: true
    },
    tax: {
      type: String,
      label: 'Taxes',
      optional: true
    },
    category: {
      type: String,              
      optional: true,
      autoform: {
        type: "hidden",                
        label: false
      },
      defaultValue: 'Test Category'
    }
  });

  {{> quickForm id="invoiceForm" buttonContent="Insert" buttonClasses="btn btn-primary btn-sm" schema=Invoice type="method" meteormethod="saveInvoice"}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you can have a field in your aldeed Schema that will render/ get saved in the form as a hidden field. So I suggest you pass the data (which you originally wanted to pass a a hidden field) though Sessions.

For example, if you are using autoform >> meteormethod to save the form, then you can save the session content within the server method. If you are not using a method, then you might want to pass the hidden data through Autoform.hooks >> onSubmit

Comment: Thanks, that what I ended up doing through Autoform.hooks

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's best to keep the logic related to the form to the `quickform` template, for the case you would reuse your schema in another form, for instance.

I'd recommend you to do the following:

```
... 
},
category: {
   type: String,              
   optional: true,
   defaultValue: 'Test Category'
}
...
```

And use the `omitFields` clause (note you can specify multiple fields to be omitted separating them by comma):

```
{{> quickForm id="invoiceForm" buttonContent="Insert" buttonClasses="btn btn-primary btn-sm" schema=Invoice type="method" meteormethod="saveInvoice" omitFields="category, foo, bar, ..."}}
```

I've noted you are using `method` as the form type. If you are manually setting a method for saving your data, you might consider specify default and auto values inside the method itself. It will give you more freedom and control over your data.

Comment: Thanks but I am not trying to hide fields from my form, instead I am trying to have two fields which won't have any UI representation on the form, yet will exist in the HTML code where each of those two fields will have a value...make sense? Thanks again

Comment: Any reason why you want these fields to "exist in the HTML code" but be hidden? It serves no purpose. You could use defaultValue or autoValue to have them take specific values. This would anyway have to be done as the fields are not shown to the user.

Comment: @kaoskeya Well I have a case where it is needed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not making the category field optional? There seems to be a conceptual problem between having a `defaultValue` and having the field as `optional`.